# Storyboard is very slow

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, storyboard

So I've been working on a project for a while that has so many view controllers, but I notice that now when I try to do a single edit in any view , storyboard hangs, or become unresponsive . what would be the solution for this issue ? is it possible at my current state to split up the whole storyboard into smaller ones ? and will that resolve the problem ? I'm using Xcode 9.3

Comment: My suggestion would be to divide storyboards into smaller ones. Relatively fast way to do that would be to use storyboard references.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226

Comment: @bseh ok thanks , lmme try this and see how it goes

Comment: Select Your `storyBoard` uncheck **Automatically Refresh Views** from **Editor**

Comment: One best practice even says to have one ViewController per Storyboard and link them up programmatically instead of using visual segue transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can have more than one storyboards in one project. In fact that's the preferred way to manage very large projects. To create more storyboards go to File Menu > New > File... and then select Storyboard from the User Interface section. Doing this should resolve your issue. However, if the issue still persist you can consider taking out the specific user interface into its own .xib file.

[image]

**Update:**

If I were in your position I would have considered using .xib files to create my user interface instead of using storyboards. Storyboards do have their advantages but there are some cons too if you use them. Like:

- If you work in a team you will run into merge conflicts more often because someone else made a change in the storyboard.
- I am still not a Guru in S/W design but, to me it seems like Storyboards violate the Single Responsibility Principle of S/W design.
- You won't be using Segues in complex ui flows anyways so what's the point of having every thing in one file.
- You won't be able to reuse your UITableViewCells interface. Prototype Cells are a good idea but if you have a UITableViewCell which is used in more than one UITableView you will have to replicate the UI in Storyboard.
- In my experience, in a more complex and large project having everything in one Storyboard makes it even hard to comprehend the UI/UX flows as Segues from every view controller seem to connect with every other view controller to the point where it just stops making sense at all.

Comment: yeah that would be great for new projects ,but now I'm trying to fix this issue with a project that has around 50 view controllers

Comment: @Mimma try the way I mentioned in comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is best **practise to distribute viewConrollers into multiple storyboards** so that you can open it quickly but it can lead your time to manage each storyboard identification programatically while accessing into code.

Otherwise, you can set storyboard **View as : iPhone 5C** so that it can load little bit faster than bigger devices.

Refer: [image]